# Fastest algorithm to find the largest n such that x^n<=y

Tags: c, algorithm, math, gmp

I am working on a project that requires me to find largest n such that x^n<=y where x and y are provided. I am using the gmp library and working with huge numbers in c.

Constraints:

x>=1 &
y>=1

Using the first approach that came into my mind, it took me around 5 secs to find n when x=12 and y = 411^20000 i.e,

```
int n=0;
int x=12;
int y=100;
int temp;
int answer;
while(1)
{
    temp = pow(x,n);
    if(temp>y)
        {
            answer = n-1;
            return(0);
        }
   n++;
}
```

Note: Not actual code. Didn't want to complicate things with gmp syntax

Is there a faster algorithm?
Entire code:
https://pastebin.com/J1vbmEbK

Comment: Well, even if you don't want to post complete code we still need the algorithm.

Comment: A little improvement would be to iteratively multiplicate instead of calculating each and every power

Comment: Even if you post pseudo-code, please try to use real functions like `exp` instead of the bitwise exclusive-or operator.

Comment: I'm probably not understanding the constraints of your problem, but why not just compute the answer directly, `floor( log(y)/log(x) )`? `log(y)/log(x)` is how you compute log-base-x(y), where `log` is just the natural logarithm (or any logarithm that's handy).

Comment: and btw, in your *pseudo-code*, `n` is constant.

Comment: @klutt my entire code:https://pastebin.com/pP2efGGQ

Comment: @FelixPalmen I had considered that.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude From now on.

Comment: @FelixPalmen My bad i will fix it.

Comment: Post does not specify if code needs to work with `x` or `y` less than/equal  zero.  Please specify.

Comment: @chux code doesnt need that.

Comment: @rjpj1998 A good up-vote-able post would "code doesnt need that" (or the like), _in the post_ and not simply far down in a comment.

Comment: @chux I didn't think it was that important.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If `gmp library` contains logarithm function, use it

```
result = Floor(log(y)/log(x))
```

Otherwise you can exploit `binary search` - `square x (x, x^2, x^4, x^8)` while possible, then diminish power step

Quick and dirty implementation for checking with usual numbers

```
returns 24 for x = 2; y = 31415926.0;
(same as Floor(ln(y)/ln(x))

int FindXPower(double x, double y) 
{
  int Powers[64];
  double t, s, next;
  int ix;

  //exponential search phase
  ix = 0;
  t = x;
  while (t <= y)
  {
    Powers[ix++] = t;  //remember them to use later
    t = t * t;
  };
  //now powers contain [x,x^2,x^4,x^8,x^16...]

  ix--;
  int Result = 1 << ix;  // 2^lastindex: 1,2,4,8,16,32...

  //binary search phase
  s = Powers[ix--];     //max value after squaring
  while ((s < y) && (ix >= 0))
  {
     t = Powers[ix];
     next = s * t;
     while (next < y)
     {
      s = next;
      next = next * t;
      Result = Result + (1<<ix);
     }
     ix--;
  };
  return Result;
}
```

Comment: No logarithm function in gmp. Damn, I feel like crying.

Comment: This repo should contain an extension for GMP which allows you to compute the log. https://github.com/linas/anant . I would still go for the binary search approach though.

Comment: @DavideSpataro why would you prefer binary search over the log method?

Comment: One can get to the ballpark by dividing y._mp_size / x._mp_size, which is roughly equivalent to log256.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen: Very roughly. A much more accurate estimate is [`(mpz_sizeinbase(y, 2)-1)/mpz_sizeinbase(x,2)`](https://gmplib.org/manual/Miscellaneous-Integer-Functions.html).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of linearly decreasing `n` you could search for the correct value by dichotomy.

Define two variables: `n_low` and `n_high` with the invariant that at any moment in time `x^n_high` is strictly greater than `y` and `x^n_low` is less than or equal to `y`.

At each iteration, compute the value of `m` which halves the distance between `n_high` and `n_low`.

Then compare `x^m` with `y`. If it is strictly greated, then assign: `n_high = m` else assign `n_low = m`. When `n_low+1==n_high` the value of `n_low` is the value you're looking for.

Comment: n is increasing lineary, and if you set the value of the max interval of your dichotomy to y, I'am not so sure you will be that faster.

Comment: I think I will stick with the binary search approach from the answer by MBo.

Comment: @rjpj1998 it is the same thing ;)

Comment: Man, I am sorry. I should have realized it. Such algorithms are new to me and it looked quite daunting lol.

Comment: @rjpj1998 no problem, MBo solution is better explained

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're working with arbitrary-precision integers (GMP also supports arbitrary-precision floating point).

- Convert the bigints to floating-point. This will incur rounding errors.
- Estimate the result computing `n_est = floor(log(y_float) / log(x_float))`.
- The actual `n` is either `n_est - 1`, `n_est`, or `n_est + 1` which can be checked easily.